# Do the two types of extended real number systems originate in algebraic geometry?

Tags: real-analysis, algebraic-geometry, soft-question, terminology, math-history

There are at least two types of extended real lines: the *affinely* extended real line, $\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty, \infty  \}$, and the *projectively* extended real line, $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$.

The latter can be identified with the real projective line $\mathbb{RP}^1$ so it is clearly related to algebraic geometry. However, both the terms "projective" as well as "affine" occur quite frequently (at least it seems to me) in algebraic geometry -- affine/projective varieties, affine/projective changes of coordinate systems, etc. There also seems to be a concept of affine extension; I am not sure.

Does the term "affinely extended real line" also come from algebraic geometry? Or is "projectively extended real line" the only one of the two which is related to algebraic geometry?

Comment: Hi - My area of specialty in math (when I was a professional mathematician) was algebraic geometry, and I never heard the phrase "affinely extended" real line. In any case, it almost certainly did NOT originate in algebraic geometry, but in real analysis.

Comment: I agree with @mathguy that the _affinely extended_ real line has nothing to do with algebraic geometry. Note that _affine_ has many meanings not substantially related to algebraic geometry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine